# MySQL sort by the request order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'd like to know how to do a request ordered by what is asked first.

Example:

```
SELECT name from user WHERE (guid = '6131bb732f6eec946e2121d1dc616019' OR guid = '62fdb8ecb0d5b7444f55aeba23fd606c' OR guid = 'f19fd7262163573abcf585d94fa74857')
```

I'd like the result not to be ordered by id or anything else but with the 6131* result, then 62f* and then f19fd*

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: See FIELD() (and see IN())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name 
from user 
WHERE guid = '6131bb732f6eec946e2121d1dc616019' 
OR guid = '62fdb8ecb0d5b7444f55aeba23fd606c' 
OR guid = 'f19fd7262163573abcf585d94fa74857'
order by case when guid = '6131bb732f6eec946e2121d1dc616019' then 1
              when guid = '62fdb8ecb0d5b7444f55aeba23fd606c' then 2
              when guid = 'f19fd7262163573abcf585d94fa74857' then 3
         end
```

or

```
SELECT name 
from user 
WHERE guid in ('6131bb732f6eec946e2121d1dc616019', '62fdb8ecb0d5b7444f55aeba23fd606c', 'f19fd7262163573abcf585d94fa74857')
order by field(guid, '6131bb732f6eec946e2121d1dc616019', '62fdb8ecb0d5b7444f55aeba23fd606c', 'f19fd7262163573abcf585d94fa74857')
```